# max function with DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, max

I'm using pandas 2.0.3 in spyder this is the code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

people_dict = {
"birthyear": [2001, 2002, 2000],
"children": [np.nan ,3 , 0],
"hobby": ["Biking", "Dancing", np.nan],
"weight": [68, 83, 112]
}

people =  pd.DataFrame(people_dict)

print(people.max(skipna=False))
```

the error showed:
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

but in my teacher device it's working

but in my teacher device it's working .so, is this a problem in this version ?

Comment: What is your teacher's pandas version? What would be the expected output?

Comment: print(people.max(skipna=True, numeric_only=True)) should work....which version is your pandas?

Comment: its pandas 2.0.3 and it must give (birthyear    2002.0
children        3.0
weight        112.0) and thank you it is working :) @HildermesJoséMedeirosFilho

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to compare numbers only and avoid the fact that nan comparison always return false.

just change the last line

```py
print(people.max(skipna=True, numeric_only=True))
```